# hyperlink sort database

Tags: php, sorting, hyperlink

i want to do sorting by clicking on the hyperlinked column header...

yes i managed to do it if i put sql statement in the if condition ..

example

```
td> <a style="width:100px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:white" href="?run=Process">Process</a></td>
```

php ;

```
$run = $_GET['run'];
if($run=="Process")
{
$sql = "select * from audit";
}
```

but the problem here... i want to assign sql statement before the if condition~

when i assign

```
  $sql = "select audit.user,audit.tarikh,activity_ref.activity from audit left join activity_ref on audit.taskID = activity_ref.idactivity_ref 
   where audit.user = '".$_SESSION['USER']."'";
```

or

```
$user = $_POST["searchUser"];

if($user)
{
        $sql = "select audit.user,audit.tarikh,activity_ref.activity from audit left join activity_ref on audit.taskID = activity_ref.idactivity_ref 
       where audit.user = '$user'";
}
```

the if condition == process does not understand $user value / $_session['User'] value..
ive assigned them with some value at the beginning.

ive been trying for all day long.. i guess i dont understand the concept well can you help me :( ..

Comment: Sorting is via an `order by` clause, which you don't have anywhere in your sql samples.

Comment: ho i forgot to mention im testing out the normal sql statement first.. but it cant recognice php variables.

Answer (score 0):

it happened because i forgot to put this code ~

```
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
{


}
```

it should be like this

```
     if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
{
    $run = $_GET['run'];
    if($run=="Process")
     {
        $sql = "select audit.user,audit.tarikh,activity_ref.activity from audit left        join activity_ref on audit.taskID = activity_ref.idactivity_ref 
         where audit.user = '".$_SESSION['USER']."'";

    }
}
```